# Problem with screen resolution when using 2 external screens

Tags: ubuntu, intel-graphics, resolution, hdmi

I have a problem with the resolution on one of the screens when using 2.

This is my system
[image]

I have tried this. The option shows up in the list of resolutions but can not be applied.

```
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-1-1 3840x2160_60.00
```

For some reason, my DELL screen is recognized as a Synaptics. It's not about the screen. If I just connect this as the only screen it works.

[image]

Well, I have tried everything I can think of. I believed xrandr could be my way out of this but apparently not.
I am trying this over HDMI screen to dock station. It's a Lenovo Carbon X1